# How can I solve a toolbar bug with DataTemplates?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, datatemplate, toolbar

(Wpf, .Net4)

Hey, 
When I use a Data Template with DataType (and no key) it only applies in the constructor.
(I must use it that way because I have two different type).
The thing is, it works on .net 3.5, and now I need to upgrade to .net 4. (I played with the properties of the project and saw that it's working on 3.5)
This is the entire code (except for the default App.xaml):

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Name="me"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Items}">
            <ToolBar.Resources>
                <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Class1}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ToolBar.Resources>
        </ToolBar>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="1"  Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();
            Items.Add(new Class1() { Title = "1" });

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Class1> Items { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Items.Add(new Class1() { Title = (Items.Count + 1).ToString() });
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The button adds items dynamicly, we can see the first one shows its title, and the dynamicly added items doesn't have a template applied.
What can I do? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently after rendering `Toolbar` doesn`t use default `Class1` template anymore. There are several solutions that can work here depending on requirements.

**1)** Define `DataTemplate` in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TestWPF:Class1}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Assuming you have some other resource dictionaries there as well. If not, `DataTemplate` can be placed right into `Application.Resources` without all that Dictionary stuff.

**2)** When an object doesn`t have a default template it just uses its `ToString` method to represent itself visually. So your `Class1` (and others) can override `ToString`:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return Title;
    }
}
```

**3)** Standard WPF approach for ItemControls - have `ItemTemplate`:

```
 <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Items}">
     <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
 </ToolBar>
```

But you said that there are several types that should have templates so for this to work you will have to implement [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) for `ToolBar`.

Comment: Thanks, the solution with the resource dictionary works.
I tried the ItemTemplateSelector solution but it requires me to put the DataTemplate in the App.xaml resource, cause it doesn't have the DataTemplate on the ApplyTemplate method.
Also, can you please explain why it applies the template when its on the App.xaml but not in the Window resources?

Comment: ItemTemplateSelector is not that restrictive. You can find plenty of tutorials [out there](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector). As for DataTemplate location - I\`m not sure. I\`ll dig into it when get some spare time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fourth workaround for this issue - you need to use another collection to form new toolbar content and then assign the value of this collection to Items